# Find Max Number in String of Numbers

Tags: java, string, numbers

I have run into an interesting problem and wanted to know if anyone had any leads on how to solve it. When given a string of numbers, I want to find the highest number. So if the string is "2836", then the output should be 8, if the string is "12345" then the output should be 5 and so on. Here is the method I am working on:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        max("215");
    }

public static void max(String number) {

    if (number.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("The string is empty");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int compCount = 1;
    int max = number.charAt(0);
    int compare = number.charAt(compCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {

        if (max > compare) {
            compCount++;
        } else if (compare > max) {
            max = compare;
        } else {
            System.out.print(max);
        }
    }

    System.out.print(max);

}
```

When this code executes it gives me 50 and I want 5

Comment: This problem is no different from having an *array* of integers and finding the maximum number in that array. Can you solve that problem? If so, then you can solve this one.

Comment: you aren't updating `compare` How do you expect it to run ?

Comment: Your description given does not really match the semantics of your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have a lot of wrong stuff going on. **Firstly**, you never change `compare`, **Second**, you take the `int` in ascii, and don't convert it to its `Integer` representation. **Thirdly**, you need only one `if` statement. All combined, it gives

```
int max = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(0));
for (int i = 1; i < number.length(); i++) {
    int compare = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i));
    if (max < compare) {
        max = compare;
    }
}
return max;
```

I've used [Character#getNumericValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) to convert the `char` to `int`

Answer (score 0):

Since ASCII codes of digits are sorted in ascending order you can easily do it with Java 8 like this:

```
public static void max(String number) {
    if (number == null || number.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    int max = number.chars().max().getAsInt();
    System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue((char) max));
}
```

If your input can has mix of digits and other symbols you also able to handle it:

```
public static void max(String number) {
    if (number == null || number.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    OptionalInt max = number.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).max();
    if (max.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue((char) max.getAsInt()));
    } else {
        System.err.println("Provided string doesn't contain digits");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify your max method as given below

```
public static void max(String number) {

if (number.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("The string is empty");
    System.exit(0);
}

int max = Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(0)+"");

for (int i = 1; i < number.length(); i++) {
      int compare = Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(i)+"");
   if (compare > max) {
        max = compare;
    } 
}

System.out.print(max);
```

}